# Uploading Image and Fixing/Veryfing it's size with <input type="file">?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing, file-upload, request.form

I Use ASP .NET 3.5 C#, and i whould like to get the picture that the user trying to upload from

`<input type="file" name="uploadPicture" id="uploadPicture">` Can i just use:

```
Request.Form["uploadPicture"];
```

And what next?

Never played around with uploading files with forms,
I wish to save this file on my File System and save the path on the database.

I need also to check the format, size and dimensions, and maybe even resize it if possible.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the following code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default7.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default7" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <input type="file" name="uploadPicture" id="uploadPicture">
    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Upload" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Default7 : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string baseImageLocation = Server.MapPath("Images\\");
        HttpFileCollection uploads = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;

        HttpPostedFile file = uploads["uploadPicture"];
        string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower();
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        if (fileName != "")
        {
            if (fileExt == ".jpg" || fileExt == ".gif")
                file.SaveAs(baseImageLocation + fileName);

        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

you can get image size from HttpPostedFile as below

```
  int size = file.ContentLength;
```

and for image height and width you can used the following function

```
 private void GetHeightAndWidht(string image)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(image);
        int height = bmp.Height;
        int width = bmp.Width;
    }
```

Comment: `HttpFileCollection uploads = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;`
Always returns an empty collection...

Comment: @Danpe:Please check that you have set enctype attribute in form section (enctype="multipart/form-data")

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```
HttpFileCollection files = Request.Files;
```

Comment: ** `HttpFileCollection files = Request.Files;`
Thanks, What's next?
I run through the Collection, I dont see any format check/resize/size check.

Comment: Use Foreach loop and access all file u can use google for fileformat/resize/size