# HttpPostedFile uploadfile = files["RemoteFile"]; returns null in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Hi i am using Dynamicsoft web Twain for scanning images.I am using their existing code and it works fine when i  am testing it in my test application.

But when i merge same code in my main project then i get Null value in second  line:

```
 HttpFileCollection files = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
    HttpPostedFile uploadfile = files["RemoteFile"];
```

I am very surprised that i am testing same code in another test application and its working fine,But don't know the reason why its not not working when i am merging same code in main application.

I have tried this link but it did not work for me.

[Uploading Image and Fixing/Veryfing it's size with <input type="file">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858330/uploading-image-and-fixing-veryfing-its-size-with-input-type-file)

Can anyone please suggest  why i am getting null value.Is there something i need to add to page directive  or master page?

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Did you verify that the `Files` collection has an item in it? You're getting `null` because there is no file with that name in the HTTP request. Use the debugger to figure out exactly what is in the `HttpFileCollection`.

Comment: @NathanAldenSr  you are right when i run test application then i am getting   {string(1)}  in  files collection but when i run my main project then i am geting null  {string(0)}.What is the reason same code and same server.Can you please suggest something?

Comment: If there are no files in the `Files` collection then chances are no file was actually included in the HTTP request. Use Fiddler to inspect the problematic request.

Comment: what could be the reason because both applications are running locally.One is working and other is not?

Comment: There are too many answers to that question. It's going to be up to you to use available tools (Fiddler, IIS logs, Visual Studio's debugger) to figure that out.